# Getting Error while setting Launchimage in XCode 6.1 in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios8, splash-screen, xcode6.1, launchimage

Hi I am developing iOS application using XCode 6.1.
When i am trying to set launch image it giving error like below.

**Asset Catalog compiler error.**

**None of the input catalogs contained a matching launch image set named  "LaunchImage".**

I searched for this problem i am unable to find exact solution.

Someone help in this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a new set of launch images:

1. In Xcode, Click on your Assets file (Images.xcassets) in the left sidebar. It should open in the main pane.
2. In the left sidebar of the main pane (where `AppIcon`, `LaunchImage`, etc. are), right click
3. Select `New Launch Image`
4. Add your new launch images.
5. Change the `Launch Images Source` from your Target's settings.

Remember to set your launch images source by viewing your target and clicking on the 'General' tab, then scrolling down.

[image: add launch image]

Comment: I follow the same steps as you mentioned.
Change the Launch Images Source from your Target's settings. Where i need to change?